# Can't get correct autoformat on save in Visual Studio Code with ESLint and Prettier

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

in Visual Studio Code with ESLint and Prettier when working on .vue files, it seems I can't get vue/max-attributes-per-line to auto-fix correctly.

For example, with vue/max-attributes-per-line set to 'off', and I try to add line breaks manually it corrects it to always have every element on no more than one line, no matter if it is 81, 120, 200, or more characters wide.  **How can I figure out what is forcing my markup elements onto exactly one line?**

I am using ESLint version 5.1.0 and Visual Studio Code (without the Prettier Extension), with Prettier 1.14.2.

Here's the example in a .vue file-- I cannot make this go on multiple lines no matter what I do, when  `'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 'off'`.  Every time I save, it forces the long line of markup to be all on one line.

```html
<template>
  <font-awesome-icon v-if="statusOptions.icon" :icon="statusOptions.icon" :spin="statusOptions.isIconSpin" :class="['saving-indicator', 'pl-1', 'pt-1', statusOptions.iconClasses]" />
</template>
```

If I set `'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 2`, it formats like so, with one line break(which is quite wrong as well).

```html
<font-awesome-icon
  v-if="statusOptions.icon" 
  :icon="statusOptions.icon"
  :spin="statusOptions.isIconSpin"
  :class="['saving-indicator', 'pl-1', 'pt-1', statusOptions.iconClasses]"
/>
```

If I try to reformat it manually, it just reverts to the above when I save.

Additionally, it seems to reformat twice when I hit Ctrl+S: first it reformats to put it all on one line, then a half-second later the formatting above results.  **Any ideas**?  What is causing this weirdness--are there multiple reformatters running? How do I figure out what the first one is to disable it?

VS Code workspace settings:

```json
{
  "editor.formatOnType": false,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": false,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2
  },
  "[vue]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2
  },
  "[csharp]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 4
  },
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterFunctionKeywordForAnonymousFunctions": true,
  "javascript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true,
  "vetur.validation.script": false,
  "vetur.validation.template": false,
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
  "eslint.options": {
    "extensions": [
      ".html",
      ".js",
      ".vue",
      ".jsx"
    ]
  },
  "eslint.validate": [
    {
      "language": "html",
      "autoFix": true
    },
    {
      "language": "vue",
      "autoFix": true
    },
    "vue-html",
    {
      "language": "javascript",
      "autoFix": true
    },
    {
      "language": "javascriptreact",
      "autoFix": true
    }
  ],
  "editor.rulers": [
    80,
    100
  ]
}
```

.eslintrc.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    jest: true
  },
  globals: {
    expect: true
  },
  extends: [
    'prettier',
    'plugin:vue/recommended',        // /base, /essential, /strongly-recommended, /recommended
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',   // turns off all ESLINT rules that are unnecessary due to Prettier or might conflict with Prettier. 
    'eslint:recommended'
  ],
  plugins: ['vue', 'prettier'],
  rules: {
    'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 'off',
    'prettier/prettier': [            // customizing prettier rules (not many of them are customizable)
      'error',
      {
        singleQuote: true,
        semi: false,
        tabWidth: 2
      },
    ],
    'no-console': 'off'
  }
}
```

Without changing any settings, `ESLint --fix` does indeed format properly--breaking all my .vue template elements into many lines properly. **So any ideas how I whip VS Code into shape?** The above settings didn't help, but I am at a loss how as to even know what is interfering. Any ideas?

To emphasize, when I save in VS Code, a long HTML element will collapse to one line then break to two lines a half-second later, all from one save operation. I'm expecting it instead to break it up into many lines. It would be okay if it took several saves, but instead the first save shows this behavior as well as every subsequent save.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I even copied your `.eslintrc.js` and workspace settings. You mentioned not using the Prettier extension, but your workspace settings show Prettier settings (what extension uses those settings?). Do you have a link to a GitHub repo that reproduces the problem?

Comment: It's highly recommended to use "Vetur" when working with VueJS & VS Code:  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur   (4.7 million downloads)

Comment: Having the exact same issue... any luck on this issue?

Comment: Tony, I'll see if I can.  I am using ESLint with the prettier ESLint plugin, not the prettier VS Code extension.  It is prettier+eslint that is supposed to do all this formatting and what this problem is about.

Comment: Bennett, I already have vetur.

Comment: Your workspace settings show Prettier config (one of which is `"prettier.singleQuote": true,`), which implies there's a Prettier VS Code extension you might not be aware of (and which may be causing the formatting conflict you're observing).

Comment: At first, I didn't know whether such Prettier settings were needed or not, so I left them.  But now, I removed the prettier config from VS's settings, as they weren't doing anything--you are right that they seem to be for the prettier extension, which I do not have nor want.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Short answer: I needed: **`"editor.formatOnSave": false, "javascript.format.enable": false`**.

I finally found the magical combination of settings, thanks to [this thread from Wes Bos on Twitter](https://twitter.com/wesbos/status/960599071164698625?lang=en).  I was right in my suspicion that there seem to be multiple conflicting formatters.  Though I'm not sure what they actually are, I was able to turn off all but eslint as follows:

In the VS Code settings, I need:

```json
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"javascript.format.enable": false,
"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
"eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
"eslint.options": {
  "extensions": [ ".html", ".js", ".vue", ".jsx" ]
},
"eslint.validate": [
  { "language": "html", "autoFix": true },
  { "language": "vue", "autoFix": true },
  { "language": "javascript", "autoFix": true },
  { "language": "javascriptreact", "autoFix": true }
]
```

In .eslintrc.js, then I can use the settings in my original post and then also change 'vue/max-attributes-per-line' as desired.  Then VS Code's ESLint plugin will format code one step at a time on every save, much as kenjiru wrote.  One last snag: HMR won't pick up these changes, so rebuild from scratch.

Comment: Our fates were intertwined. Ditto situations and explanations. Following you from https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/557. Worked for me as well

Comment: Spent more time setting prettier and eslint to work correctly than actually coding -.- Your answer helped a lot, thanks! 

Edit: It seems to be working well with javascript.format.enable: true
If you want to keep VSCode formatter to work for other files (json, gql, etc.) instead of `"editor.formatOnSave": false` add this line to settings.json:

 "[javascript]": {
  "editor.formatOnSave": false
 },

Comment: In some cases, it might be enough to go into the ```User Settings```, search for eslint, then activate the checkbox for ```Eslint: Auto Fix On Save```

Comment: This has been a real pain for me lately. This answer finally fixed it! Though I was able to remove the jsx/react stuff. Thanks!

Comment: If you're working in WSL, remember that there are different settings for User / WSL / and Workspace! Set `"javascript.format.enable": false` in User and WSL.

Comment: Not working for me - since some of the dependencies are deprecated. Here my issue: https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/557

Comment: `"eslint.formatOnSave` is now:

 `"editor.codeActionsOnSave": { "source.fixAll.eslint": true}`

Answer (score 5):

With `'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 'off'` the rule is disabled so VSCode does not try to fix the long line on autosave. Other eslint fixes are applied, as expected.

With `'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 1` VSCode fixes only one error per save. This is a known limitation of *vscode-eslint*

*vscode-eslint* only does a single pass in order to keep to a minimum the amount of edits generated by the plugin. The goal is to keep as many markers (like break points) in the file as possible.

VSCode has a time limit of 1 second for all the plugins to compute the change set on save. If one of the plugins causes the other plugins to not run for 3 times in a row, it will be disabled.

`eslint --fix` runs all the rules in a loop until there are no more linting errors. I think it has a limit of 10 iterations maximum.

See these links for more details:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/154

I've created a minimal setup to demonstrate this issue:

- https://github.com/kenjiru/vscode-eslint-onsave-issue

Comment: This is not at all the behavior I am seeing. With 'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 'off', the long line is forced onto one line no matter how many line breaks I add.  With 'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 1, the long line is broken only once no matter how many times I press Ctrl+S.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You got this behavior with my repository?

Comment: This sample repository works on my machine, so seems quite likely to be another extension running first that we are not yet aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts; they weren't exactly my problem but helped nudge me to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but in case anyone should find this and not have success with the posted solutions, the fix for me was to add:

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
   "source.fixAll": true
}
```

I did not need `"editor.formatOnSave": true` for some reason. I do **not** have Prettier installed - only ESLint - but this now performs any fixes automatically when I save.

Answer (score 2):

This is the setup I ended up going with in VSC `settings.json` file.

Works perfectly for locally set up `eslint` disabling the default vetur settings (if the plugin is installed).

```json
"files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.fixAll.eslint": true
},
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"javascript.format.enable": false,
"eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
"eslint.options": {
  "extensions": [ ".html", ".js", ".vue", ".jsx" ]
},
"eslint.validate": [
  "html",
  "javascript",
  "vue"
],
```

Comment: This works great thank you! I felt the need to say it because each time I saved a file, immediately I had to hit cmd + z to undo the autosave changes. My life is normal again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this things and it didn't worked.

```json
"typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false,
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false,
"typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingEmptyBraces": false,
```

but it at last i tried this. and worked
`"diffEditor.wordWrap": "off"`,

Answer (score -1):

I bumped into the same issue, and surprisingly found that prettier and vetur were conflicting. I had to disable vetur formatter and it now works as expected.

If you have this section in your editor's `settings.json` and you have prettier installed,

```js
{
 "[vue]": {
     "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur",
  },
}
```

chances are, these two formatters are conflicting and thus the unexpected behaviour.

A quick workaround is to comment it as below, or simply delete it permanently.

```js
{
 "[vue]": {
     // "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur",
  },
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I've struggled through a similar problem. I tried the solution above but didn't work for me, unfortunately. I'm using eslint and Vetur, didn't install prettier plugin but configured it via eslint and enabled "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true. I finally got the correct autoformat on save by removing the following configuration in settings.json. Not sure why but it's working for me.

```js
"eslint.options": {
  "extensions": [".html", ".js", ".vue", ".jsx"]
},
"eslint.validate": [{
    "language": "html",
    "autoFix": true
  },
  {
    "language": "vue",
    "autoFix": true
  },
  {
    "language": "javascript",
    "autoFix": true
  },
  {
    "language": "javascriptreact",
    "autoFix": true
  }
]
```

Will update this answer if I get other issues related to this.

Comment: Not working and for now `autoFix` is set as true in default.