# Why is vscode formatting my code twice upon saving?

Tags: eslint

I have my editor set to fix all issues upon saving. However, once I saved, it formats the code to fix the issues, then a split second later reverts back to the original unfixed and unformatted code. This started happening after I updated vscode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get correct autoformat on save in Visual Studio Code with ESLint and Prettier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102705/cant-get-correct-autoformat-on-save-in-visual-studio-code-with-eslint-and-prett)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by following the steps outlined in this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52259752/9491881

Short answer: I needed:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"javascript.format.enable": false
```

Answer (score 10):

Not saying this will be your case, but worth checking:

1. Make sure this setting is false: `"editor.formatOnSave": false`
2. Add this to the `settings.json` file :

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
```

If you don't use ESLint / Prettier installed, then do the opposite, meaning just make sure that `formatOnSave` is set to true and you don't have other formatters enabled.

Comment: Saved couple of hours! thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it really killed me as I uninstalled prettier and eslint, reset the rules and everything...

Until I saw I had that `lonefy.vscode-js-css-html-formatter` package, which is silent in the settings but still forces its own opinionated formatting rules. Uninstalling it made the trick :)

Comment: I had this issue with stylelint, uninstalling lonefy instantly fixed the problem.